# Setting up non-Admin user account in Drupal / CiviCRM - Menu bar not visible

Tags: user-account

When I create a user account with authenticated user permissions + some additional create/edit permissions, the Drupal Menu-bar or the CiviCRM menu-bar doesn't show. Only when I add the admin privileges to the user account, do I see the menu bar. So how is a non-admin person supposed to navigate between the various modules (contact/ membership/ event/ contribution etc.) without having full admin rights? Am I missing something? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you given them 'CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API'?

Comment: There is this one person we are training up to do back-end work, like imports, creating and running reports etc. I was hoping that we'd be able to give her all rights except delete rights to start with, but I couldn't do that. So I gave her full admin rights. But other volunteers will be using forms/ profiles to add/edit records and won/t need back-end access.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a Menu Block or just a Block with some links and set it in to a region with settings so it only shows for Authenticated

But also, am unclear if you really want a non-admin person getting to those 'modules'.

If a non-admin person is making donations, registering for events they do not need access to CiviCRM itself.

Perhaps update your Q with more detail about what the non-admin person needs to access perhaps by providing the paths you want them to get to so you avoid saying 'member page' which could be construed in many ways. HTH

Comment: Hi Pete, we have volunteers who enter data for membership or events registration. So we want them to have add/edit rights but not delete rights. We don't want to give them full Admin privileges, So they need to be able to access some of the menu items (to be able to access the contact, contribute, membership and event menu nodes) but not the administer node. Does this make sense?

Comment: Hi Raja Yes - and in those scenarios we tend to limit those folk to just the drupal side of things by giving them Views and Webforms so that all their searching and updating/adding can be done without using civi itself - but can't say that is a good solution in your use case

Comment: Thanks Pete, what you say makes sense. Will need to do more research on this option.

Comment: Hi Raja - would be good if you either added more info or +1 and accepted the answer